# Php Script To Get Excel, Pdf And Text Files From Database

Tags: php, file, cron, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I want to creating a PHP based script to get mysql data into excel, text and pdf files. Here excel and text directly from the data base and need to generate a decorated pdf from html on daily bases and remove old files daily. Also need to know how to use cron in localhost lamp.
Can any one help me.

Comment: I have tried to create excel using PHPExcel library, but unable to export this files and also don't know how to how to use CRON to get this export on daily bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done it by using PHPExcel ..here is an example:
     `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

```
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $col = 1;
        $struc=array(
                "Col 1",
                "Col 2",
                "Col 3"
        );
                    $alphas = array("A", "B", 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N','O', 'P','Q','R','S');

        $styleArray = array( 'font' => array( 'bold' => true, ), 'alignment' => array( 'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT, ), 'borders' => array( 'top' => array( 'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN, ), ), 'fill' => array( 'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR, 'rotation' => 90, 'startcolor' => array( 'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0', ), 'endcolor' => array( 'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF', ), ), );

        foreach ( $struc as $key => $val){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($key, $col, $val);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($alphas[$key])->setAutoSize(true);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($alphas[$key]."1")->getBorders()->getBottom()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($alphas[$key]."1")->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        }

        $col++;
        foreach ( $items as $item){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $col, $item->xname.' '.$item->xfamily);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,$col, $item->col1);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $col,$item->col2);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $col,$item->col3);
            $col++;
        }

        $styleArray = array(
                'borders' => array(
                        'allborders' => array(
                                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                        )
                )
        );
        $excelRow = 2;

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="user-report-'.$this->view->PersianDate(date("Y-m-d"), "%d", false).'.xls"');
```

$objWriter->save('php://output');
`

Comment: How can we get HTML to pdf using PHPExcel library..

Comment: you cant...use TCPDF for generating PDF using HTML

Comment: I have tried with HTML2PDF library but Can I get this HTML to pdf from PHPExcel do you have any idea ?, And please tell me what to do for cron to execute this script daily.

Comment: no..PHPExcel is just for getting a xls or csv export from database or such...i have used HTML2PDF ...it is not as power full as TCPDF...

Comment: if my answer worked for you accept it

Comment: Yes, Its working but two more things there I want to answering from you. Q1. What to do for text file ? Q2 What to do for CRON RUN on daily basis ?

Comment: for cron first set a method for creating your file and then set a cron job on your server or host. and for text file ,it depends on how you want to store your data and your data complexity. so saving database info into a text file is hard and kinda bad in my oponion

Comment: was my comment help full for answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need not use PHPExcel to generate an Excel file usoing data from the database.

You can do it even without it by using a \t for every column and a \r\n at the end of every line.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/ will give you a detailed explanation of how to do it

Use PHPExcel for reading or making more complicated files

Comment: How can we get HTML to pdf using PHPExcel library...